# Эмулятор интернета

Tags: android, эмулятор, netcat

Условия задачи:

Есть телефон, он подключен к моему(доверенному) WiFi. На нем стоит apk который хочет переслать серверу данные. APK устанавливает соединение и отправляет информацию на сервер.

Задача:
С компа надо установить на какой сервер/порт обращается телефон и заблокировать весь исходящий от него трафик. Далее установить соединение с телефоном от имени того, к кому он обращался (сервера) и дождаться данных которые apk отправляет.

Итого: нужна программа, которая подменяет собой выход в интернет. Для телефона всё буднично, спокойно - а мы анализируем что в это черном ящике происходит принимая исходящие из него данные и посылая(!) свои запросы.

Вопрос: есть ли какие либо уже готовые решения? Слышал про netcat, не знаю, то это или нет. Посоветуйте что использовать, какой инструмент лучше применять?

Comment: fidler часто используют для подобных целей. А вообще решений много. гуглить по словам `traffic sniffer`

Comment: Для перехвата трафика мне еще нравиться charles 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HeK-AdFpzM